# Mountain Lion on brand new MacBook Air gives warning that it's using Legacy FileVault?

Tags: macos, osx-server, filevault, open-directory

I set up FileVault a month ago on this new machine. Everything seemed to be working fine. But now when I go to `System Preferences>Security & Privacy>FileVault` when logged into a Mobile Account I get a warning that:

> You’re using an old version of FileVault.
>
> You’re using an older version of FileVault that encrypts your home directory 
>   but not the entire disk. Do you want to keep using the older FileVault?

Though `Legacy FileVault` was pre-Lion?!? This machine can't even run Lion, let alone Snow Leopard...

This warning doesn't occur when logged into a Local account. It only pops up when logged into a Mobile account. The way our Macs are setup there is typically just one local `admin` user and all other users are mobile Open Directory accounts on our OS X (also Mountain Lion) Servers.

What gives?

Comment: Perhaps Legacy FileVault is being used on the server?

Comment: Server is new hardware and running Mountain Lion as well…

Comment: Are the mobility options set to encrypt the home folder (in Workgroup Manager, it's Mobility preferences -> Account Creation tab -> Options subtab -> "Encrypt contents with FileVault" checkbox)?

Comment: Problem persists... To answer @GordonDavisson's question, these mobility settings on the ML Server are set to "Never". The MacBook Air has FileVault 2 enabled (and that is all that was set up. But now when visiting Security & Privacy System Preference we get the warning described in OP (above) and there's a new "Legacy FileVault" tab alongside the "FileVault" tab!?!